# Laravel - serve with custom port without --port option

Tags: laravel

Is there any way to serve a laravel application in a custom port without using `--port` or any web servers like nginx, apache, ... ? maybe we can change source codes. is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution 1

You can go to this file:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php
```

and change the default port at the line 87.

```
87     ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 8000],
```

This way will let you use `php artisan serve` command with that port you set in that file. (Default is 8000).

But remember it is not recommended to change code inside vendor folder.

---

#### Solution 2

you could make an alias with wanted port, something like:

```
paserve=php artisan serve --port=8080
```

and then when you call `paserve` you get the app served on that port

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is great! But I made a different solution that worked very well for me on Laravel 8

First of all, create a new command using:

`php artisan make:command RunServer` or any name you want

Then I copied the content inside `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php` class to my `RunServer` class

(Remember to change the `protected $name`, i used `'run'` instead of `serve`)

And all I have done was add a new .env variable Eg.: `APP_DEFAULT_PORT`

Add a new variable on `config/app.php` => `'default_port' => env('APP_DEFAULT_PORT'),`

and call this variable inside my `RunServer` class changing this line

`$port = $port ?: 8000;`

to

`$port = config('app.default_port');`

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan make:command RunServer`

`RunServer` class should be extened from original `ServeCommand`.

Rename the command, in my case it 'run' in `protected $name`

Add `getEnvPort()` method, see below. It extract port from APP_URL if it is specified.

Override protected `port()` method (copy all code of them). It has changes only on this line `$port = $port ?: $this->getEnvPort();`

In the `.env` set:
`APP_URL=http://localhost:9090`

Then

`php artisan run`

`yarn dev` (it also get port from APP_URL)

Enjoy it!

```
class RunServer extends ServeCommand
{

    protected $name = 'run';

    /**
     * @return int|mixed|string
     */
    protected function port()
    {
        $port = $this->input->getOption('port');

        if (is_null($port)) {
            [, $port] = $this->getHostAndPort();
        }

        $port = $port ?: $this->getEnvPort();;

        return $port + $this->portOffset;
    }

    protected function getEnvPort(): ? int
    {
        return parse_url(config('app.url'), PHP_URL_PORT) ?: 8000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, speaking about setting up a default port to listen to it's not necessary to create a custom command but just to set SERVER_PORT=<a free port number> in .env file.

Since v5.8 up to now ServeCommand getOptions() function is taking care about the SERVER_PORT environment variable and that is the easiest solution for such a case:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php#L115

Best,
K.